# Does "as well as" makes sense here:

Tags: grammar

Is the below sentence grammatically correct.

The Annual Report highlights our financial performance in 2018, as well as our citizenship, corporate governance and talent related activities from throughout the year.

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem is *from*. The word *throughout* is doing the job and *from* looks as if it were left behind in an edit.

From would require a range, such as from January to December, or a period such as last year. "... and talent related activities from last year." The words *throughout the year* will cover that. Choose one, not both. I would go with *throughout*.

Comment: While I don't disagree with your nswer, you have not actually addressed the original Q., which was "Does '*as well as*' makes sense here".

Comment: Your comment is quite correct. The as well as is correct as used here.

Comment: May I suggest that you amend your Answer accordingly?